# Getting a row from mySQL database if the price has been reduced

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to display only the products that have reduced set as 'yes' in the database but i am receiving the following error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /reduced.php on line 79`

reduced.php

```
<?php
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname','name','password');
                $reduced = 'yes';
                $result = $pdo->query('SELECT file_id, productName, price, stock, reduced FROM files WHERE reduced = '.$reduced.'');
                foreach($result as $row){
                    echo "<div id='shop'>";
                    echo "<img id='product' src=\"file.php?id={$row['file_id']}\">";
                    echo '<p>' . $row['productName'] . '</p>';
                    echo '<p>' . "£" . $row['price'] . '</p>';
                    echo '<p>' . "Stock Level: " . $row['stock'] . '</p>';
                    echo '<a href="basket.php">ADD TO BASKET</a>';
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the quotes try

```
 $result = $pdo->query('SELECT file_id, productName, price, stock, reduced FROM files WHERE reduced = "'.$reduced.'"');
```

Comment: Thank you very much